# Extending Python: process numpy arrays

Tags: python, c++, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I wrote an extension for Python 3 in C++

My module is capable of handling arrays like `[1.0, 0.0, 0.0]`.
I want to add support for numpy arrays as well.

I process arrays with the following code:

```
PyObject * MyFunction(PyObject * self, PyObject * args) {
    PyObject * list;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O!:MyFunction", PyList_Type, &list)) {
        return 0;
    }

    int count = (int)PyList_Size(list);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        double value = PyFloat_AsDouble(PyList_GET_ITEM(list, i));

        // ...
    }
}
```

I want a function that can iterate through this: `np.array([2,3,1,0])`

**TL;DR:**

Numpy equivalent for:

- `PyList_Type`
- `PyList_Size`
- `PyList_GET_ITEM` or `PyList_GetItem`

Comment: No real answer and maybe you got good reasons to use this native way of interfacing c++, but did you consider [cython](http://cython.org/). This makes all that stuff much easier/nicer and is used by some very cool projects (e.g. scikit-learn).

Comment: normally, it's the other way round: you write a numpy-function, which also can handle lists.

Comment: I just wan't to be able to iterate through a numpy array in C++

Comment: Now I will check `cython` @sascha

Comment: @DombiSzabolcs A short overview/comparison regarding numpy/c++ interfacing: [link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.python-as-glue.html)

Comment: I wan't to build a python extension and upload it on PyPI *(wheel and source)* so `cython` is not solving my problem now.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but what's the problem there? Cython surely needs a C++ compiler (which could be awkward for windows-users) if you are interfacing C++ code, but the same should apply to the native-bindings. A lot of projects use cython and are available on PyPI.

Comment: I must do more reading then.

Comment: I have a module that seems to be stable, currently I am using `gcc` to create windows binary formats for `PyPI`. For example [Buffer Creation](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL/blob/master/Source/ModernGL-Buffer.cpp) expect data implementing the buffer interface. *(ie: bytes)* so `struct.pack` is used on lists. numpy arrays' representation in memory is great for buffer creation but I cannot get the pointer and size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is no `numpy` equivalent for:

- PyList_Type
- PyList_Size
- PyList_GET_ITEM or PyList_GetItem

The `numpy.array` implements the [buffer interface](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html), so one can write:

```
const char * data;
int size;

PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "y#:MyFunction", &data, &size);
```

The `numpy.array([1.0, 0.0, 0.0])` uses `double` precision:

```
double * array = (double *)data;
int length = size / sizeof(double);
```

**The full example:**

- **C++**

  ```
  PyObject * MyFunction(PyObject * self, PyObject * args) {
      const char * data;
      int size;

      if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "y#:MyFunction", &data, &size)) {
          return 0;
      }

      double * content = (double *)data;
      int length = size / sizeof(double);

      for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
          double value = content[i];

          // ...
      }

      Py_RETURN_NONE;
  }
  ```
- **Python**

  ```
  MyFunction(numpy.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]))
  ```